# What is the best option of a graduate multivariate statistics book?

Tags: statistics, measure-theory, reference-request, statistical-inference, book-recommendation

Right now I am in the middle of a graduate multivariate statistics but I am feeling to easy at the moment. As a mathematician I study univariate statistics from "The theory of statistical inference : Shelemyahu Zacks" wich is a completely theoretical with measure formalism and I want to know if it exists an analogue for multivariate.

I have been recommended to look for statistics from differential geometry perspective ... But also I don´t found anything interesting.

Could someone help me with references on books, papers ... ?

Comment: This depends somewhat on what you expect to study from a multivariate statistics book. Could you mention some topics under this course?